# Color and text overlay on hover over an image with perforated edge

Tags: html, css

I have multiple images with a perforated edge on on the left and right of the image. I need to have a blue color overlay on hover with some text on top. Currently the overlay does not take on the shape of the image which looks odd. Is there a way to create this edge using css or another method so that when the overlay is added it matches the image's edge?
Thank you for your help in advance!

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1bUjgS-HG5b4Txt7sS03c0QGkMDiQ2kgh" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creating the effect *can* be done with CSS (using a repeating radial gradient I think) but, if I recall, it requires a **fixed** size for the inset "cuts" and so it would not be responsive.

Comment: I you have a standard shape for all the images you need to use this on, you can use a CSS alpha mask: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-mode

Comment: @ChrisBarr Thank you so much! This is a game changer.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped!  I've never used it before but have known about it. I tried to play around with it using your existing image but couldn't get it to work but I would imagine that exact image isn't the right one to use for a mask.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I created a new image in photoshop with the center blacked out and the perforated edge transparent. I wrapped the puppy image in a div and applied the mask to the new div and then added:     
-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;

I will update the code on here once the project is complete, worked beautifully though.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I was picturing would be needed. Glad it works!